# xml child node looping with 2 for each statement

Tags: xml, xslt

my xml

```
<data>
<node name="a" link="www.a.com">
<node name="b" link="www.b.com">
   <subnode name ="b1" link="www.b1.com">
<node name="c" link="www.c.com">
</data>
```

my xslt

```
<xsl:template match"/">
<xsl:for-each select="data/node">
    <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
       <xsl:value-of select="@link">
    </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name">
    </a>

     <xsl:for-each select="data/node/subnode">
    <a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
       <xsl:value-of select="@link">
    </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name">
    </a>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

output

```
a
b
c
```

expected output

```
a
b
    b1
c
```

the code above is work fine but doesn't meet my expected output, how can i only loop my subnode if my subnode is existed ?

Comment: Are you sure about the example input? It is not well-formed XML right now.

Comment: And the XSLT code is not well-formed XML either. For example, `<xsl:template match"/">` lacks a `=` and the `xsl:value-of` elements are not closed. This is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template, as written, is expecting a document in the form:

```
<data>
    <node name="a" link="www.a.com" />
    <node name="b" link="www.b.com" />
    <data>
        <node>
          <subnode name ="b1" link="www.b1.com" />
        </node>
    </data>
    <node name="c" link="www.c.com" />
</data>
```

due to the XPath `data/node/subnode`. Change this to:

```
</a>
<xsl:for-each select="subnode">
    <a>
```

and it should work.

Note that I'm assuming your example has been edited; it is currently invalid XML, but the results you have given are consistent with a well-formed document.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could shorten your code considerably. XSLT is a functional programming language where `for-each` is inappropriate in many places. You clearly don't need to use it.

A couple of other things:

- both your input XML and XSLT code are *malformed XML*. No XSLT processor or XML parser would accept them. Be more careful when posting questions here.
- the actual and expected output you show do not reflect the instructions in your XSLT stylesheet. Always show XML output (except you'd like the output to be *text*, of course).

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="node|subnode">
   <a href="{@link}">
       <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   </a>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a href="www.a.com">a</a>
<a href="www.b.com">b</a>
   <a href="www.b1.com">b1</a>
<a href="www.c.com">c</a>
```